# Download a csv file from harvard dataverse

Tags: r, file, download

I want to download the following data set https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/M3D2NR using R instead of making the user do it manually. One has to go to the web, select the file and then press "download". Is there a way to make it automatic using R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tricky part is to find out the url, where the file is hosted. Once you find that out, you can use `download.file` and providing appropriate destination address to save it

[image]

```
download.file("https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/3086908?gbrecs=true", 
               paste0(getwd(), "/filename.csv"))
```

Comment: @Maja just clicked `Inspect Element` on the Download button on the page and clicked some random tabs ;-)

Comment: Great to know this exists. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a great tip for a single file. I explained a similar method for multiple files (with screenshots) at https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse/issues/4529#issuecomment-499564457

Answer (score 1):

There is also a dedicated Dataverse client for R ([GitHub](https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-r#data-download), [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataverse/index.html)). This package offers a function `get_dataframe_by_name` that lets you specify the dataset via DOI and filename, without hunting for the file location. You can find the [documentation here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataverse/dataverse.pdf) and some snippets on how to download files [in the project README](https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-r#data-download).

Your code should look something like this:

```
# Install package from CRAN
install.packages("dataverse")

downloaded_data <-
  get_dataframe_by_name(
    filename    = "AMPD_Unit_with_Sulfur_Content_and_Regulations_with_Facility_Attributes.csv",
    dataset     = "10.7910/DVN/M3D2NR/0DXVG7",
    server      = "dataverse.harvard.edu",
    original    = TRUE,  # Download the original file and not the ingested version
    .f          = readr::read_rds  # Specify the function to read the file. Use a CSV reader here 
  )
```

If the file contains tabular data that has been ingested by Dataverse, you can drop the `original` and `.f` parameters.